# Unique number assignment to a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, delphi, pascal

I am trying to write R*C/2-1 unique numbers into an array , but the random function gives multiple times the same value.
It should be filled with each number 2 times at a random position.

Like:

```
 ( 1 2 3 4 )
 ( 5 6 7 8 )
 ( 1 2 3 4 )
 ( 5 6 7 8 )
```

My code so far:

...

```
R=4
C=4
```

...

```
 var
    somearray : array [0 .. (C- 1), 0 .. (R- 1)] of integer;
```

...

```
    for Row := 0 to (R - 1) do
     for Col := 0 to (C - 1) do
      begin
        somearray [Col, Row] := RandomRange(0, 9);
       end;
```

...

EDIT1:

second array

...

```
var
   maxnum: array [0 .. (C * R) div 2 - 1] of integer;


max := (C * R) div 2;
for i := 0 to max - 1 do
  maxnum[i] := i;
```

...

maxnum has numbers from 0..7 / 1-8

Comment: Do you care about the distribution? Do you want it to be uniform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this that I can see:

### Random Position

Iterate through the numbers and then place each one at a random position. If you hit a conflict position then you would have to have some logic to find the next position for that value.

Using your code we would get:

```
// Initialize the array
for Row := 0 to (R - 1) do
  for Col := 0 to (C - 1) do
    somearray[Col, Row] := 0;
// Populate the random numbers
for randomCount := 1 to 2 do
  for randomNumber := 1 to ((R * C) div 2) do
  begin
    randomPosition := Random(R * C);
    while somearray[randomPosition div C, randomPosition mod C] <> 0 do
    begin
      Inc(randomPosition);
      if randomPosition >= (R * C) then
        randomPosition := 0;
    end;
    somearray[randomPosition div C, randomPosition mod C] := randomNumber;
  end;
```

Putting this in a more generic form:

```
type
  T2DArray = array of array of Integer;

procedure RandomPopulate1(aTheArray: T2DArray);
var
  col: Integer;
  colCount: Integer;
  randomCount: Integer;
  randomNumber: Integer;
  randomPosition: Integer;
  row: Integer;
  rowCount: Integer;
begin
  // Initialize the array
  colCount := Length(aTheArray);
  if colCount = 0 then
    Exit;
  rowCount := Length(aTheArray[0]);
  for col := 0 to colCount - 1 do
    for row := 0 to rowCount - 1 do
      aTheArray[col, row] := 0;
  // Populate the random numbers
  for randomCount := 1 to 2 do
    for randomNumber := 1 to ((colCount * rowCount) div 2) do
    begin
      randomPosition := Random(colCount * rowCount);
      while aTheArray[randomPosition div colCount, randomPosition mod colCount] <> 0 do
      begin
        Inc(randomPosition);
        if randomPosition >= (colCount * rowCount) then
          randomPosition := 0;
      end;
      aTheArray[randomPosition div colCount, randomPosition mod colCount] := randomNumber;
    end;
end;
```

To use this:

```
var
  somearray: T2DArray;
begin
  Randomize;
  SetLength(somearray, 4, 4);
  RandomPopulate1(somearray);
end;
```

### Using random position changing

You could set the values in the array and then randomize the positions. So perform a number of random swaps. This is the easier option.

```
// Initialize the array
for Row := 0 to (R - 1) do
  for Col := 0 to (C - 1) do
    somearray[Col, Row] := ((Col * C + Row) div 2) + 1;
// Now randomize the positions
for randomLoop := 0 to (R * C) - 1 do
begin
  randomPosition := Random(R * C);
  randomNumber := somearray[randomLoop div C, randomLoop mod C];
  somearray[randomLoop div C, randomLoop mod C] := somearray[randomPosition  div C, randomPosition  mod C];
  somearray[randomPosition  div C, randomPosition  mod C] := randomNumber;
end;
```

As before we can have a more generic version:

```
procedure RandomPopulate2(aTheArray: T2DArray);
var
  col: Integer;
  colCount: Integer;
  randomLoop: Integer;
  randomNumber: Integer;
  randomPosition: Integer;
  row: Integer;
  rowCount: Integer;
begin
  // Initialize the array
  colCount := Length(aTheArray);
  if colCount = 0 then
    Exit;
  rowCount := Length(aTheArray[0]);
  for col := 0 to colCount - 1 do
    for row := 0 to rowCount - 1 do
      aTheArray[col, row] := ((col * colCount + row) div 2) + 1;
  // Now randomize the positions
  for randomLoop := 0 to ((colCount * rowCount) div 2) do
  begin
    randomPosition := Random(colCount * rowCount);
    randomNumber := aTheArray[randomLoop div colCount, randomLoop mod colCount];
    aTheArray[randomLoop div colCount, randomLoop mod colCount] :=
        aTheArray[randomPosition div colCount, randomPosition mod colCount];
    aTheArray[randomPosition div colCount, randomPosition mod colCount] := randomNumber;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: 3 sounds easy , can you check the main post again ? lets say we have a second array but how to assign a number twice from it to the somearray

Comment: @user5353405 I took out the third option because it's just a more complex variant of the second one.

Comment: Certainly the second option does not distribute uniformly. I'm not sure about the first. I'd do this using a shuffle as per your second, but take care over the shuffle so that it is uniform.

Comment: This looks like a situation where a shuffle is the best solution. This fills the array with values 0..size - 1 in consecutive order and then shuffles them, which is a random swap but structured (each item is - probably - swapped once). Another solution are DeBruijn sequences..

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks for the suggestion. I will update the answer to use a more structured shuffle.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, thanks. Understand now what you were referring to.

Comment: It's called Fisher-Yates shuffle

Comment: But unless I'm mistaken, the answer is still not uniform. On the other hand, the asker apparently does not care about the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The random function is not designed for this type of use.

Instead:

- create a list (array) of the values desired, presumably 1 .. R*C/2.
- randomly rearrange them.
- fill the array with the randomly arranged values.

Comment: Yes I already tried with a second array , but how to I assign the values of array2[i] to somearray[Col,Row] ? Without duplicates.

Comment: Simply randomly rearraging does not guarantee that all positions are considered. A [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) does..

Comment: @Rudy That's an imprecise way to state it. The precise mathematical way is to refer to the distribution. The point of Fisher-Yates is that it results in the **uniform distribution**. It's possible to have non-uniform shuffles.

Comment: Ok, imprecise. I did refer to Fisher-Yates, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

1. Create a dynamic array (or `TList<integer>`) with the number of items equal to the number of cells in your 2d array.
2. Fill this array with sequential integers. For example, assign 1 to Item [0], 2 to Item[1] etc.
3. Generate a r:=Random(List.Count). Assign the List[r] value to your 2d array member and delete the member from the list.
   This will result in decrement of List.Count and the new r generation will give you a i) Distinct item value even if the index is the same. ii) The random function will ever give you an item index within the remaining part of the primary array until Length(List)=0.